# Filter trough an array and get the nested array back

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is my countries array:

```
[
  {
    "countryCode": "HU",
    "countryName": "HUNGARY",
    "cities": [
      {
        "cityCode": "BUD",
        "cityName": "BUDAPEST"
      },
      {
        "cityCode": "DEB",
        "cityName": "DEBRECEN"
      },
      {
        "cityCode": "ZLG",
        "cityName": "ZALAEGERSZEG MA BUS STATION"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "countryCode": "GB",
    "countryName": "UNITED KINGDOM",
    "cities": [
      {
        "cityCode": "ABZ",
        "cityName": "ABERDEEN"
      },
      {
        "cityCode": "ACI",
        "cityName": "ALDERNEY"
      },
      {
        "cityCode": "ADX",
        "cityName": "ST ANDREWS"
      },
     ]
   }
  }
]
```

I use react-hook-form, I subscribed to the country filter:

```
const countryName = form.watch('countryName');
```

and I am trying to make a cities array like:

```
const cityOptions = countryOptions.filter(country => {
   console.log(country.countryName, countryName); // output: HUGNARY HUNGARY
   return country.countryName === countryName && country.cities;
}
```

I logged out countryName that I am watching in the form and also country.countryName inside the cityOptions and it found match, but it returns an array with the Hungary object not the cities inside:

```
[
    {
        "countryCode": "HU",
        "countryName": "HUNGARY",
        "cities": [
            {
                "cityCode": "BUD",
                "cityName": "BUDAPEST"
            },
            {
                "cityCode": "DEB",
                "cityName": "DEBRECEN"
            },
            {
                "cityCode": "ZLG",
                "cityName": "ZALAEGERSZEG MA BUS STATION"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

What could be the issue I am not seeing?

Comment: What is `countryOptions`? Is it the `countries` array in the first snippet?

Answer (score 1):

Use `find()` to find the country you want, then extract its `cities` array.

```
const cityOptions = countryOptions.find(c => c.countryName == countryName)?.cities;
```

Answer (score 0):

Understand operator precedence here. Your code will evaluate right side of the condition before comparing it countryName.

`return country.countryName === countryName && country.cities;`

Go with this.

```
const cityOptions = countryOptions.filter(c => c.countryName == countryName)?.cities;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the condition, your filter returns the expected result when the condition is met, that is the whole object. To get the cities data you can pass the result to the `flatMap` method like that:

```js
const countryOptions=[{countryCode:"HU",countryName:"HUNGARY",cities:[{cityCode:"BUD",cityName:"BUDAPEST"},{cityCode:"DEB",cityName:"DEBRECEN"},{cityCode:"ZLG",cityName:"ZALAEGERSZEG MA BUS STATION"}]},{countryCode:"GB",countryName:"UNITED KINGDOM",cities:[{cityCode:"ABZ",cityName:"ABERDEEN"},{cityCode:"ACI",cityName:"ALDERNEY"},{cityCode:"ADX",cityName:"ST ANDREWS"}]}];

const countryName = "HUNGARY";
const cityOptions = countryOptions
  .filter(country => country.countryName === countryName && country.cities)
  .flatMap(country => country.cities)
  


console.log(cityOptions)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method is basically creates a shallow copy of a portion of the given array and return the whole item/object that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

To get the `cities` array, There is two ways :

- Access the first and only `0`th index object (As you are comparing with the `countryName` filter, I am assuming the filter method you wrote will always return a single object in an array) and then access the cities property using dot(`.`) notation.

  ```
  cityOptions[0].cities
  ```
- As [`@Barmar`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) suggested, You can use [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method to find the country you want, then extract its cities array.